# How do you call the "type signature" vs the "function implementation"

Tags: notation

I often throw around signatures like:

$$f: X \times X \to X$$

and

$$f: (x_1, x_2) \mapsto x_1 \cdot x_2$$

But how do you call these kinds of signatures?

EDIT: Some clarification:

1. The first version maps sets and uses $\to$
2. The second version maps variables and uses $\mapsto$

How do you call these different kinds of notations, because you usually write down both for a specific function (one to show domain and codomain, second to show the graph)

Comment: Not very clear...

Comment: The symbol $f : X \times X \to X$ means that $f$ is a *function* from the *cartesian product* of the set $X$ with itself into the set $X$. Example : $+ : \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is the *sum* of *natural* numbers. It maps every pair $(n,m)$ of naturals into their sum $n+m$.

Comment: The second line doesn't make much sense to me; I would write it as $$f: (x_1,x_2)\mapsto x_1+x_2.$$

Comment: I think of $f:X\times X\to X$ as the same kind of thing as $x\in X$, and I don't know a specific name for that either.